# Facebook Ads API - Create News Feed Ad Preview

Tags: facebook, api, ads, preview

Currently when I attempt to generate an ad preview by calling...

```
FB.api('/my_ad_acct_id/generatepreviews?creative={}')
```

... with the proper creative spec passed, I always receive a 'Right Hand Column' type of preview, regardless of the creative.

My assumption was to then set the `targeting` parameter, passing in...

```
{'countries':['US'],'page_types':['desktopfeed']}
```

.... which should force a News feed placement and the result is the same.

How do you get a news feed preview from the `generatepreviews` API call?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is at the bottom of this, right after "Create an ad preview by specifying page post details":

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/generatepreview/

This is a working call to generate a Newsfeed preview for a sponsored post:

```
GET /act_xxxxxxxx/generatepreviews?page_type=desktopfeed&creative={"type":27,"object_id":page_id}&post={"link":"http://www.facebook.com","message":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet","picture":"http://url.to/your/custom/image.jpg","name":"Facebook","caption":"www.facebook.com","description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"}
```

This will return an `iframe` pointing to the actual preview.

The downside is that you must construct the preview object *entirely* and not just using a `creative_id` or `ad_id` (I think. If not, I would be pleased to know how to do it with just an object id though the Graph API).

Good luck, I hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook used to provide only right hand side previews in the `generatepreviews` endpoint. As of January 20 you can use the `page_type` parameter to specify which placement is being previewed. Possible values are `rightcolumn`, `desktopfeed`, and `mobile`. You get the preview markup if the creative is allowed in the placement specified. If you specify this optional parameter you get an iframe in the response, so there is no need to make an additional request for the preview stylesheet.

Parameters available for this endpoint is documented here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/generatepreview/